# How to implement a return * statement in C?

Tags: c, return

I was reading about recursive ascent-descent parsers  [here](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/3-540-53669-8_70.pdf).

In section 2.1, they describe a return *  statement,

> Our C extension occurs with return statements. We have used
>   the notation return * k to indicate that a k-level function return is to be made. That
>   is, return * 1 is identical to the normal C return statement and simply returns control
>   to the caller of the current function; return * 2 means that control is to be returned
>   to the caller of the caller, and so on. Finally, return * 0 is to be interpreted as a null
>   statement. We leave emulation of the return * k construct in languages that lack this
>   operation as a simple exercise for the reader.

How can I implement such return* statements in my own code or emulate this behavior using `goto` statements or/and pointer? 
Are there any languages that provide this functionality by default?

Comment: The article says "The corresponding recursive ascent-descent parser, coded using a small extension to C, is shown in Figure 1. " This reads like they change the C compiler. The code example in "Figure 1" of that article really shows `return * 1;` I fear you need that changed C compiler to follow the approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `setjmp()` and `longjmp()` to emulate this multi-level return, as long as you take care to maintain a stack of `jmp_buf`s every time you call a function.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define MAXDEPTH 10
jmp_buf stack[MAXDEPTH];
int sp = 0;

#define CALL(f)                                                                \
  do {                                                                         \
    assert(sp < MAXDEPTH);                                                     \
    if (setjmp(stack[sp++]) == 0) {                                            \
      f;                                                                       \
    }                                                                          \
  } while (0)
#define RETLEVEL(n)                                                            \
  do {                                                                         \
    if ((n) > 0) {                                                             \
      sp -= (n);                                                               \
      assert(sp >= 0 && sp < MAXDEPTH);                                        \
      longjmp(stack[sp], 1);                                                   \
    }                                                                          \
  } while (0)
#define RETURN                                                                 \
  do {                                                                         \
    sp -= 1;                                                                   \
    assert(sp >= 0);                                                           \
    return;                                                                    \
  } while (0)

void f3(void) {
  printf("In f3(), sp is %d, returning back 2 levels\n", sp);
  RETLEVEL(2);
}

void f2(void) {
  printf("In f2(), calling f3(), sp is %d\n", sp);
  CALL(f3());
  printf("Returning from f2(), sp is %d\n", sp);
  RETURN;
}

void f1(void) {
  printf("In f1(), calling f2(), sp is %d\n", sp);
  CALL(f2());
  printf("Returning from f1(), sp is %d\n", sp);
  RETURN;
}

int main(void) {
  printf("In main(), calling f1(), sp is %d\n", sp);
  CALL(f1());
  printf("Returning from main(), sp is now %d\n", sp);
  return 0;
}
```

When compiled and run, this outputs:

```
In main(), calling f1(), sp is 0
In f1(), calling f2(), sp is 1
In f2(), calling f3(), sp is 2
In f3(), sp is 3, returning back 2 levels
Returning from f1(), sp is 1
Returning from main(), sp is now 0
```

Read up on those functions, though, as they come with a few caveats about local variables holding their values between `setjmp()` returns.

---

As for languages that have a built-in multi level return... tcl comes to mind with [`return -level N`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/return.htm). Any language with continuations, like scheme, or coroutines can probably emulate it easily, though.

Comment: This is going to be super slow. If you're happy to wrap all calls and returns in macros there's a much simpler solution.

Answer (score 2):

The `setjmp` solution suggested by @Shawn should work, as long as it doesn't overflow the setjmp stack (and remember that recursive ascent parsers may require a reasonably large stack), but it imposes a pretty significant overhead on every call in order to slightly optimise returns which skip over a few stack frames.

In the recursive ascent model, the number of frames skipped is small, often 0. So the overhead will be large and the savings small.

You could write a somewhat faster solution using [libunwind](http://nongnu.org/libunwind) (see `unw_step()` and `unw_resume()`), but note that `unw_step` treats the call stack as a linked list (which is what it is), and therefore can only step over a single stack frame at a time. So you end up with a loop around `unw_step` calls. Also, you'd have to make sure that no function call was inlined.

A much simpler and faster solution is to simply wrap `CALL` and `RETURN` in macros, as @shawn suggests, and use the otherwise-unused return value to count unwinds: (Slightly modified to use variadic macros)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sp = 0;

#define CALL(f, ...)                            \
  do {                                          \
    ++sp;                                       \
    RETLEVEL(f(__VA_ARGS__));                   \
  } while (0)

#define RETLEVEL(n)                             \
  for ( int n__ = n; n__ > 0 && sp > 0; ) {     \
    --sp;                                       \
    return n__ - 1;                             \
  }
#define RETURN RETLEVEL(1)

int f3(void) {
  printf("In f3(), sp is %d, returning back 2 levels\n", sp);
  RETLEVEL(2);
}

int f2(void) {
  printf("In f2(), calling f3(), sp is %d\n", sp);
  CALL(f3);
  printf("Returning from f2(), sp is %d\n", sp);
  RETURN;
}

int f1(void) {
  printf("In f1(), calling f2(), sp is %d\n", sp);
  CALL(f2);
  printf("Returning from f1(), sp is %d\n", sp);
  RETURN;
}

int main(void) {
  printf("In main(), calling f1(), sp is %d\n", sp);
  CALL(f1);
  printf("Returning from main(), sp is now %d\n", sp);
  return 0;
}
```